# Exception thrown at 0x0F4D514F (vcruntime140d.dll) in Project70.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xDDDDDDDD

Tags: c++, class, new-operator, undefined-behavior, memory-mapped-files

I am trying to change a class member's value that created in heap with address and getting the error down below.

```
class class2 {
private:
    string String = "x";
public:
    string function() {
        return String;
    }
};

class class1 {
public:
    string String;
    class2* i;
        void  address(class2* x) {
        x = new class2();
        i = x;
    }

        void function(string x) {
            String = x;
    }
};



int main() {
    int len;
    cin>>len;
    class1 **Class1 = new class1*[len];

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        Class1[i] = new class1[i];
    }

    Class1[0]->address(Class1[0]->i);
    Class1[0]->function(Class1[0]->i->function());
    cout<<Class1[0]->String;

}
```

> Exception thrown at 0x0F4D514F (vcruntime140d.dll) in Project70.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xDDDDDDDD.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. You can [edit]  your question. But the two stars in `class1 **Class1` don't look good, remember you're using c++, not C.

Comment: what is `new class1[i]` supposed to do?

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: I reverted your edit, it was worse.

Comment: User input is not important it's just lenght of array. @Jabberwocky

Comment: In general it _is_ important for reproducing an issue.

Comment: `0xDDDDDDDD` means freed heap memory. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations)

Comment: When i is 0, `Class1[0] = new class1[0];` is allocating zero class1 objects.  Dereferencing that array of 0 objects `Class1[0]->address` is doing UB.  After that, all bets are off.

Comment: @Eljay  UB: Undefined Behavior?  Be nice to the new programmer.

Answer (score 4):

This call of the new operator

```
Class1[i] = new class1[i];
```

is invalid. You mean

```
Class1[i] = new class1;
```

Pay attention to that this member function

```
void  address(class2* x) {
        x = new class2();
        i = x;
    }
```

does not make great sense because the passed argument to the function is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, lets take this step by step, to illustrate what's going wrong.  It's pretty clear you're learning C++, so I'll try to write to that audience.

```
    int len;
    cin>>len;
```

1) read in a length from standard in.  No serious problems yet.  You could check to be sure it's not negative or zero, but we'll let that slide for now.  We'll pretend that "len = 3", and move on from here.

```
    class1 **Class1 = new class1*[len];
```

2) you create a pointer to pointer to class1 called Class1.  I can't say that I like your naming scheme, but lets work passed that too, and set Class1 to an array of pointers to class1.  So far so good.  If `len` were zero or negative, you can imagine the problems you might have.  Note that none of the memory for those pointers has been initialized, just set aside to hold things you put in it later.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        Class1[i] = new class1[i];
    }
```

3) This will create some new instances of class1, and point Class1[I] at them.  With `len = 3`, this will create a weird grid of allocations.  The first array will be of length ZERO, the second of length 1, and the third of length 2.  ZERO length arrays are bad.

So with that zero length array ready to blow up like a land mine when we step on it, lets go for a walk!

```
Class1[0]->address(Class1[0]->i);
```

First of all, this is pretty misleading.  It would be better written as `Class1[0][0].address(Class1[0][0].i)`;  Second, passing 'i' into a function whose sole purpose is to write to a member variable that happens to be that parameter you just passed in is pointless.  Just write to the member variable.

And third:  Boom.  We just stepped on the zero-length-array-land-mine.  But all is not lost.

You can salvage this with a relatively small number of changes.

- `Class1[i] = new Class1[len];` will give you a grid of allocations (3, 3, 3) rather than a triangle (0, 1, 2).
- for every call to `new` you need a call to `delete`, preferably in that class's destructor.  Destructors are awesome.  You call `new` in `address` (remove it's parameter, you don't need it), so somewhere need to call delete.  Also, you should set `i` to nullptr in the constructor so you don't accidentally try to delete something invalid.
- for every call to `new[]` you need a call to `delete[]`.  You looped through an array calling `new[]`,  so you need to loop through that array calling `delete[]` to clean it up.
- Variable names.  I'm guessing English isn't your first language, and you're learning C++ too, so I understand.  However, your function and variable names are meaningless at best (`class1`, `class2`, `i`, `x`), and misleading at worst (`address` doesn't take anything's address, it creates something).  Even with not much to go on, you could at least use names like "InnerClass", "OuterClass", "message", "createInner", "innerPtr"... and they wouldn't be nearly as difficult to figure out.

`<RANT MODE>`
What are we, ***mathematicians***?!  We have all the space we need to describe things, so be descriptive.  Mathematicians used to be confined to a blackboard, and had to write everything by hand, so some pressure to use (overly) concise (impossible for outsiders to comprehend) notations was understandable... but now?  They don't eve have that excuse.  And I'm looking at you too Physicists!  Yeah you, in the lab coat!
`</RANT MODE>`

And learn to touch type.  Programmers end up typing a LOT, and looking from screen to keyboard and back kills your typing speed.

Comment: You're really better off ditching the native array entirely and going with `std::vector<class1>`, but I'm guessing you haven't learned about templates yet.

Comment: We've been introduced to it but in this assigment it's not permitted.